# OSError: cannot identify image file I can't get rid off the Thumb.db using Pillow in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a `dictionary` with a `list` of `image files` as `values`. My code works but now I run into this issue wit the `Thumbs.db` hidden files which is now crashing my code.

```
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import Image
import math, operator
import os

path_folders = ('F:/162 pic sets ready/')
d = {}
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_folders):
    d[dirpath] = filenames

dict2 = {k: list(map(lambda x: (k+'/'+x ), v)) for k,v in d.items()}

dict3 = {k: list(map(lambda x: Image.open(x), v)) for k,v in dict2.items()} 

OSError: cannot identify image file 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set77/Thumbs.db'
```

I tried everything I was supposed to do in my windows to get rid off the `Thumbs.db` but I still get this same error.

Comment: test if `x` is an image file.

Comment: can you show how you load `image files`.

Comment: @zetysz yes, they are image files, I tested the code in smaller test folders of images and it works as expected. However, I am using other folders now with different images and I get this error.

Comment: I used this `dict2 = {'test.py': ('test.py', '')}
dict3 = {k: list(map(lambda x: Image.open(x), v)) for k,v in dict2.items()} ` and i got this error **IOError: cannot identify image file 'test.py'**

Comment: @zetysz my issue is the Thumbs.db

Comment: Can you show content of  `dict2`.

Comment: @zetysz I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because Thumb.db is created automaticaly by windows,You should test files in for loop.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_folders):
    if someCondition:#for example if 'Thumb.db' not in filenames
       d[dirpath] = filenames
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and now I get this error: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'F:/162 pic sets ready/set69/IMG_9240.JPG'`

Comment: but I think, this may have solved the `Thumbs.db` problem so I accept your answer. Although, I still have a problem with this but this maybe and other problem.

Comment: Thanks.May be you should  modify `dict3 = {k: list(map(lambda x: Image.open(x), v)) for  k,v in dict2.items()} ` to close file after getting content, if there is 1000 files you will have 1000 files opened

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do somehow. I have to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

use this command to delete all the thumbs.db files :)
Hope this helps.Worked in my project like charm :)
Run this command in command Prompt

del /s /q "c:\thumbs.db"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you